# Is Yoda trickster?

Tags: characters

As I understand trickster is a character in a story which exhibits a great degree of intellect or secret knowledge, and uses it to play tricks or otherwise disobey normal rules and conventional behaviour. Could anybody shed light on question which buzz in my head? Is Yoda trickster? What properties of the character should I remove( assuming Yoda is not trickster ) to make Yoda true trickster?

Edited.

Comment: I think this might be better off on Sci-fi. As it is, I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, or how any of it applies to Yoda.

Comment: A trickster disobeys rules and conventions and usually has a fundamental role in creating a culture (such as bringing the knowledge to handle fire). I don't think that Yoda has that kind of role, nor does he display convention-breaking behavior. Yoda is modelled more on buddhist teachers, who often use contradiction to free the mind and generally have a humorous view on life.

Comment: Thank you What. I found few things about trickster which made me think so.

Comment: Often trickster is supernatural or divine. Yoda has supernatural power. Right?

Comment: The trickster deity breaks the rules of the gods or nature, sometimes maliciously but usually with ultimately positive effects. That's what Yoda do. Right?

Comment: Trickster is a creator, a joker, a truth teller, a story teller, a transformer linked to the spiritual frequency changes humanity. Is not that about Yoda?

Comment: To make Yoda a trickster, you must give him a different role in the story. The trickster is not part of the normal community. He is an outsider. The trickster also has an impact on a cultural change. Yoda as a trickster doesn't really fit the Star Wars saga. It would have to be a different story entirely.

Comment: Yoda went into exile on Dagobah after a lightsaber battle with Darth Sidious. He was an outsider :) He had cultural impact, founding school of jedis and shifting Luke Skywalker state of mind what made possible win good side.

Comment: Is trickster about personality of character or about his role on a specific scene?

Comment: Found more "In all of these trickster tales, the tricksters are often animals who use their wit and cunning to survive against animals that are physically stronger than they are. This often teaches the other animals the lesson that they can’t always expect to come out on top just because they are strong." Is not that about Yoda? Yoda is half meter creature which able to strike any full-scale villain.